# How do i use filter in linq against non string fields?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using jquery datatables plugin in my mvc application. filtering works perfectly against the fields with string datatype. but i cant use filtering against non string fields without enumerating the results first. here is my code.

```
 public  List<MerchAgreementMain> getAgreementbyAccountNo(jQueryDataTableParamModel model)
    {
        var entity = new CCMSEntities();
        var query = (from _first in entity.First
                     from _second in entity.Second
                     where _first.No == _second.No 
        select new MerchAgreementMain
                     {
                         AcctNo = _Account.AcctNo,   // datatype long
                         BusnName = _Account.BusnName,
                         CreatedBy = _Account.CreatedBy,  
                         CreationDate = _Account.CreationDate ?? DateTime.MinValue,  
                         Status = _Reflib.Descp
                     });
        if (model.sSearch != null)
        {
            var x = query.AsEnumerable().Where(p => Convert.ToString(p.AcctNo).Contains(model.sSearch) || p.BusnName.Contains(model.sSearch) || p.CreatedBy.Contains(model.sSearch)||
                p.Status.Contains(model.sSearch));
          this.displayRecods = x.Count();
           return x.ToList();
        }
        //var result = query.ToPagedList(Convert.ToInt16(model.sEcho),Convert.ToInt16(model.iDisplayLength));
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

this works fine. but the issue is that the query is enumerated first before applying the filters and the database contains thousands of records; that seems to be a bad practice and can take some delay before showing the filtered result. how do i apply the filter in an Iqueryable for long?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
query.AsEnumerable().Where(....
```

apply filters directly.

```
query.Where(
```

Please see: [IQueryable vs. IEnumerable in terms of LINQ to SQL queries](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231163/IQueryable-Vs-IEnumerable-in-terms-of-LINQ-to-SQL)

Since you are doing `AsEnumerable` your query is iterating first and then applying the filter. If you apply the filter without `AsEnumerable` then the query is `IQueryable` and it will apply the filters only when iterating over the resultset.

Comment: i know that. but i cannot type cast from string to long in an Iqueryable.thats why i enumerated it so that i can filter by the column that has the long datatype.